# How to store auth token and retrieve for react native by using @react-native-async-storage/async-storage?

Tags: react-native

I use Context in react native to store token and access by using @react-native-async-storage/async-storage.
When i try to console token return null while i tried to initialize 1234 in the useState hook
**Below is the Context**

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const StateContext = createContext({

    user: null,
    token: null,
    setUser: () => {},
    setToken: () => {}
})

export const ContextProvider = async ({children}) => {
    
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    const [token, _setToken] = useState('1234');

    const setToken = async (token) => {

        await _setToken(token);

        try{
            
            if(token){
                
               await  AsyncStorage.setItem('ACCESS_TOKEN', JSON.stringify(token));
    
            }else{
                
               await AsyncStorage.removeItem('ACCESS_TOKEN');
            }
        }catch(e){
            console.log(e);
        }

    }

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ 
            user,
            setUser,
            token,
            setToken
        }}>

        {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useStateContext = () => useContext(StateContext);
```